# Javascript onLoad no carga

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2015

Tengo esta función de Javascript dentro de mi HTML.

```
$("#aviso1").on('click', function (e) {
        // Initialize the object, before adding data to it.
        //  { } is declarative shorthand for new Object()
        var obj = {};
        obj.titulo = $("#Titulo").val();
        obj.informacion = $("#Informacion").val();

        //In order to proper pass a json string, you have to use function JSON.stringfy
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify(obj);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'Titulo.ashx?Num=1',
            type: 'POST',
            data: jsonData,
            success: function (data) { document.getElementById("Titulo1").innerHTML = data; },
            error: function (errorText) { alert("Whoops something went wrong!"); }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Pero si le pongo on('click'... si me despliega la información, pero cuando le pongo on('load'... no carga la información.

¿A qué se debe y como puedo solucionarlo?

EDIT: Para poder utilizar las funciones de esta forma de forma que carguen automaticamente en lugar de escribir

```
on('load' function(e) ...
```

o

```
on('click' function(e) ...
```

debe de ser

```
ready(function(e) ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El evento load únicamente se aplica al objeto raíz del DOM lo que significa que en una página puedes aplicarlo únicamente al objeto window o al document. En cualquier otro elemento no se va a generar:

[load Event Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load)

Si utilizas jQuery (como veo) y quieres que la función que ahora tienes asociada al evento click se ejecuta al cargar la página no tendrías más que hacer:

```js
$(function() {
        // Initialize the object, before adding data to it.
        //  { } is declarative shorthand for new Object()
        var obj = {};
        obj.titulo = $("#Titulo").val();
        obj.informacion = $("#Informacion").val();

        //In order to proper pass a json string, you have to use function JSON.stringfy
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify(obj);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'Titulo.ashx?Num=1',
            type: 'POST',
            data: jsonData,
            success: function (data) { document.getElementById("Titulo1").innerHTML = data; },
            error: function (errorText) { alert("Whoops something went wrong!"); }
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Titulo">Título</div>
<div id="Informacion">Información</div>
<div id="Titulo1"></div>
```

Con la sintaxis:

```
$(function(){...});
```

jQuery ejecuta la función una vez que se ha completado la carga de la página.

Answer (score 1):

Entonces ... Para que las funciones me carguen sin la necesidad de dar click debo de cambiar a:

```
$("#aviso1").ready(function (e) { ...
```

Comment: Edito la respuesta para mostrar cómo deberías hacerlo